# Default RNG used by openssl for certificate generation

Tags: random-number-generator, openssl

I have generated a certificate using `openssl` with the below command.

```
openssl ecparam -out <output_file> -name secp256r1 -genkey
```

What would be the `RNG` used in this case? and is it cryptographically secure?

Comment: It would be the standard one. And yes - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68919/70072